# How to exclude certain links when automatically targeting external links to open in a new window

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm aiming to use jQuery to automatically open all external links in a new window, but I've run into some trouble.  Here's what I'm using:

```
<script>
$('a').each(function() {
var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
if(!a.test(this.href)) {
   $(this).click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
       window.open(this.href, '_blank');
   });
}
});
</script>
```

The trouble I'm having is that within several of the pages, there is a "print this page" link that uses Print and unfortunately the above targeting is including the print function  - opening it in a new window and therein missing the content of the page, resulting in a blank print window.  Is there a simple way for me to exclude a specific ID or class from the jQuery targeting that I can then add to the print link to avoid this conflict?  Or should i be adjusting the jQuery targeting to look for an http://www.domainname.com at the start of links to avoid treating anything else as an external link?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Why are you not just using `target="_blank"` on your links?

Comment: Retroactively having to change a ton of links wouldn't be practical. Additionally client is asking for it to be an automatic thing that anything outside of their domain be opened in a new window without their many admins having to add anything to the link.  A may seem trivial, but with distributed editing responsibility, automatic is definitely a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class of 'noExt' to the ones you don't want to go external then wrap the external function in an if statement like:

```
if( !$(this).hasClass('noExt'){
    ... do external stuff . . .
}
```